# autocorrelation in evaluating time series forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around whether using Holt-Winters ETS or an ARIMA model for forecasting sales figures (which are highly seasonal).

I'm been using R and the Forecast package -- which already has seen massive improvement from my hand-coded Excel-based ETS and ARIMA models (probably because many background AIC tests are conducted and parameters possibly optimized).

In any case, I'm starting with the accuracy() function before I start hand-calculating the accuracy measures myself (so I know more what's going on).

I know what most of the measures mean, but I'm afraid I'm not exactly sure about auto-correlation. I know that means the tendency of -- well, I assume the forecast rather than the sample, which is the same for both methods --- the tendency of the forecast to correlate with itself (given lag 1, or lag n, I'm not sure).

Is this a measure of accuracy? Or model fit? Or just a 'good to know'? I'm not sure what a large, small, or negative number might mean here. Well, I do -- negative means the forecast is likely to swing the opposite direction of the past --- but how does this judge the forecast accuracy?

Thanks for your help -- I have a stack of statistics and forecasting books (Armstrongs Principles of Forecasts and Makridakis, Wheelwright, and Hyndman's Forecasting Methods) --- both are great. Armstrong's is very high level, which is great -- the other explains how to properly execute methods and the reasoning -- but I still find the nitty gritty details of my statistics and forecast knowledge lacking in some fundamentals.

Comment: Glad to see that you have read principles of forecasting by Armstrong. Autocorrelation can be used to build forecasting models or to assess forecasting model by examining the residual auto correlation to see if the forecasting model is adequate in capturing all the information in your data? Can you please clarify what is the context that you are looking at auto corr?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. It's listed along with other accuracy measures such as MAPE and MSE -- I was wondering the significance of autocorrelation in forecast evaluation/ accuracy. Perhaps that's too vague a question and it has specific uses I'm not aware of (I know it aids in model selection).

Comment: If it's listed in accuracy function, then it's most likely going to be residual auto correlation.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes sense. I take it correlated residuals simply means there exists some systematic bias in the forecast, possibly due to some underlying variable(s) that are unaccounted for? I'll take it a low residual auto correlation means a better model. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.